# Mounted samba share hangs /media and df -h when cable disconnected

Tags: samba, umount

Encountered behavior:

1. Unplugging an ethernet cable on which a samba share has been mounted will cause:
   a. the /media to become inaccessible.
   b. df -h to hang indefinitely
2. Why does this occur on (l)unix. Is there no auto dismounting execution?
3. Is there any way to resolve automatically on event of cable disconnection, as provided by a software package, configuration or execution of commands, without having to executed a unmount before removing the cable?
4. Is there a way to resolve the inaccessibility after it has occurred other than restarting the system?